# how to divide two queries

Tags: sql, influxdb

I want to divide below two queries:

**1st Query:**

```
select count_value from (select count(*) 
from jmeter 
where "project" = 'testmatrix' 
AND "suite" = 'apitest' 
AND "build"='132' 
AND "status" = 'ok' 
AND "page" != 'all' 
AND "metric" = 'count' 
AND "value"=0)
```

**2nd Query:**

```
select count_value 
from (select count(*) from jmeter 
where "project" = 'testmatrix' 
AND "suite" = 'apitest' 
AND "build"='132' 
AND "status" = 'ok' 
AND "page" != 'all' 
AND "metric" = 'count')
```

Your help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Would you like to have one SQL instead of two?

Comment: Please mention the output

Comment: 1st query out put is 1 and second query output is 2 then total output shouldbe 1/2 or 0.5

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN "Value"  = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) 
from jmeter 
where "project" = 'testmatrix' 
AND "suite" = 'apitest' 
AND "build"='132' 
AND "status" = 'ok' 
AND "page" != 'all' 
AND "metric" = 'count'
```

Comment: Please ALWAYS add explanations to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This will help.

```
select sum(f_query)/ sum(S_query) as Result 
from (
    select  count(*) as f_query , 0 as S_query from jmeter where "project" = 'testmatrix' AND "suite" = 'apitest' AND "build"='132' AND "status" = 'ok' AND "page" != 'all' AND "metric" = 'count' AND "value"=0
    union all
    select 0 as f_query , count(*) as S_query  from jmeter where "project" = 'testmatrix' AND "suite" = 'apitest' AND "build"='132' AND "status" = 'ok' AND "page" != 'all' AND "metric" = 'count'
) as GroupTable
```

Comment: Error: error parsing query: found union, expected ) at line 1, char 266 could you pleasehelp

Comment: which database server are you using?

Comment: influxdb database i am using

Comment: select sum(f_query)/ sum(S_query) as Result 
from (
    select  count(*) as f_query , 0 as S_query from jmeter where project = 'testmatrix' AND suite = 'apitest' AND build='132' AND status = 'ok' AND page != 'all' AND metric = 'count' AND value=0
    union all
    select 0 as f_query , count(*) as S_query  from jmeter where project = 'testmatrix' AND suite = 'apitest' AND build='132' AND status = 'ok' AND page != 'all' AND metric = 'count'
) as GroupTable

Comment: try above hope so it works else try to handle santax error.  I havn't installed influxdb thats why not able to check santax error. Please undearstand query logic. Its ok.